# Given that $g$ is only continuous at $0$, not on $[0,1]$, show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 g(x^n) dx = g(0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

**Important Notice**: Observe that although this question is very similar to many other questions such as the one in [proving $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} f(x^n)dx = f(0)$ when f is continous on [0,1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571845/proving-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-01-fxndx-f0-when-f-is-contin/571854#571854), this problem only assumes continuity at $0$, but not on $[0,1]$.

Here is the question:
**Assume $g$ is (Riemann) integrable on $[0, 1]$ and continuous at $0$. Show
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 g(x^n) dx = g(0)$.**

My attempt at this question: I split up the integral into two parts from $[0,1-\alpha]$ and $[1-\alpha,1]$. For $[0,1-\alpha]$, there is uniform continuity, so the limit $n \to \infty$ can be shifted inside the integral to get $g(0)$.

But how do I keep the integral over $[1-\alpha,1]$ to be small?

Note: This is Exercise $7.4.10$ in Abbott, Understanding Analysis, 2nd edition.

Comment: If you did notice the uniform continuity, I don't think the rest would be a difficulty for you, as you see $g$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ so you can have any estimation you want.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen It is given that $g$ is continuous only at $0$ and not on the whole interval $[0,1]$. From what I know, only if $g$ is continuous on the compact interval $[0,1]$, then we can claim that $g$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Ah okay, in this case, you can use the integrability

Comment: I do admit that I did not carefully read your post, it's a little bit trickier than its related version when $g$ is continuous. I'll post  an answer to your post.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen appreciate your comment(s), but can you help to provide a complete answer/response?

Comment: Is $g$ assumed to be Riemann- or Lebesgue-integrable?

Comment: Doesn't "integrable" imply "bounded" in this context [proper riemann integration]?

Comment: @StinkingBishop In this chapter of Abbott, only Riemann integration is defined and Lebesgue integration was not introduced yet. Hence, only definitions/concepts related to Riemann integration can be applied.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Suppose $g$ is bounded, I don't see how that helps in getting the complete answer. Would definitely appreciate if you can post a complete answer.

Comment: Then $g$ is bounded and $|\int_{1-\alpha}^1 g(x^n)dx|\le\alpha\sup_{0\le x\le 1}|g(x)|\to 0$ as $\alpha\to 0$.

Comment: I would just be repeating Stinking Bishop's comment.  In order, choose $\epsilon > 0$.  Then choose $\alpha \in (0,\epsilon)$ so that the integral on $[1-\alpha, 1]$ is sufficiently small for every $n$ (justified by StinkingBishop's comment).  Then choose $N$ so that $g(x^n)$ is sufficiently close to $g(0)$ for all $n > N$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1-\alpha$.

Comment: The claim that $g$ is R-integrable implies $g$ is bounded is not true.

Comment: @Zhanxiong You need the function to be bounded in order to be able to define Darboux sums in the first place.

Comment: @Guangyao: so as you want.

Comment: @Zhanxiong https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610054/if-a-function-fx-is-riemann-integrable-on-a-b-is-fx-bounded-on-a

Comment: I am agreeing with @BrianMoehring on boundedness because the definition of Riemann integrability in the reference text (where this question is posted) assumes boundedness as well.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: The duplicate answer uses only that $g$ is bounded and continuous at $x = 0$.  Since $x^n \to 0$ uniformly on $[1,1-\epsilon]$ there is $N(\epsilon)$ such that $n > N(\epsilon)$ implies $\int_0^{1-\epsilon} |g(x^n)-g(0)| \, dx < \epsilon(1-\epsilon)$.  I'll also vote to reopen if there is really a case made where all of this adds something new in addition to probably a dozen other duplicates or near duplicates of this question. The boundedness follows presumably from the riemann-integration tag. It seems the posts here already provide the OP with the required answer.

Comment: @RRL I edited the question to explicitly state Riemann integrability. This is implicitly assumed in the reference textbook because of the previous sections in it. Also, I think you made a typo in your reply above, Do you mean $x^n \to 0$ uniformly on $[0,1-\epsilon]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is straightforward if we assume Lebesgue integration
theory: Since $g$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded. Choose $M>0$
such that $|g(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. For each $x\in[0,1)$,
$g(x^{n})\rightarrow g(0)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ because $g$
is continuous at $0$. Moreover, $|g(x^{n})|\leq M$. By Dominated
Convergence Theorem, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{1}g(x^{n})dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}g(x^{n})dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{1}g(0)dx\\
 & = & g(0).
\end{eqnarray*}

Alternative approach that does not invoke Lebesgue integration theory:
Since $g$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded. Choose $M>0$ such
that $|g(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in[0,1].$ Let $\varepsilon>0$ be
given. Choose $\delta>0$ such that $|g(x)-g(0)|<\varepsilon$ whenever
$x\in[0,\delta]$. Choose $a\in(0,1)$ such that $a>1-\varepsilon$
. Observe that $a^{n}\rightarrow0$, so there exists $N$ such that $a^{n}\in[0,\delta]$
whenever $n\geq N$. Note that for any $x\in[0,a]$, we have that
$0\leq x^{n}\leq a^{n}$, so $x^{n}\in[0,\delta]$ whenever $n\geq N$
and $x\in[0,a]$. Consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|\int_{0}^{1}g(x^{n})dx-g(0)\right|\\
 & = & \left|\int_{0}^{1}g(x^{n})dx-\int_{0}^{1}g(0)dx\right|\\
 & \leq & \int_{0}^{1}\left|g(x^{n})-g(0)\right|dx\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{a}\left|g(x^{n})-g(0)\right|dx+\int_{a}^{1}\left|g(x^{n})-g(0)\right|dx.
\end{eqnarray*}
If $n\geq N$, and $x\in[0,a]$, we have $x^{n}\in[0,\delta]$, so
$|g(x^{n})-g(0)|<\varepsilon.$ It follows that $\int_{0}^{a}\left|g(x^{n})-g(0)\right|dx\leq\int_{0}^{a}\varepsilon dx\leq\varepsilon$.
On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{a}^{1}\left|g(x^{n})-g(0)\right|dx\\
 & \leq & \int_{a}^{1}2Mdx\\
 & = & 2M(1-a)\\
 & \leq & 2\varepsilon M.
\end{eqnarray*}
That is, $\left|\int_{0}^{1}g(x^{n})dx-g(0)\right|\leq\varepsilon(2M+1)$
whenever $n\geq N$. This shows that $\int_{0}^{1}g(x^{n})dx\rightarrow g(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g$ is assumed to be Riemann-integrable on $[0,1]$, then it is bounded on $[0,1]$, and we have:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}\left|\int_{1-\alpha}^1 g(x^n)dx\right|&\le&\int_{1-\alpha}^1|g(x^n)|dx\\&\le&\left(\sup_{0\le x\le 1}|g(x)|\right)\int_{1-\alpha}^1 dx\\&=&\alpha\sup_{0\le x\le 1}|g(x)|\\&\to&0\end{array}$$

as $\alpha\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to provide a full answer which includes convergence of the first integral, for reference and completeness?

Comment: @Guangyao Having seen that this question has been marked as a duplicate, I don't believe I can add much to the accepted answer there: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/571854/700480 .

Comment: @StinkingBishop Hmm, I don't want to be involved but you know, in your link $f$ is assumed to be continuous on $[0,1]$ but in this case, it's only at $0$  the function $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Yes, I would like to highlight that continuity is only at $0$, and not on $[0,1]$. Hence, it is not a duplicate. I added an additional note to explain this in the question. Hope you will be able to add more details to make the answer complete. Thanks

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Can you point where, in the accepted answer, they use continuity at any other point than $0$?

Comment: Well, if you see that as duplicate, so please go ahead.

Comment: They use that $\sup_{x\in[0,1]} |g(x)| < +\infty$ which does not follow from integrability of $g$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @mechanodroid We are apparently assuming Riemann-integrability here (see the discussion below this question).

Comment: Also note riemann-integration tag, but OP needs to be clear otherwise we can answer this with dominated convergence.

Comment: True, I'm just noting where was continuity of $g$ on $[0,1]$ used in the linked answer.

Answer (score 1):

So here is a quick answer because I kinda wanna stay out of any possible discussion at the moment.
**Answer**
WLOG: $g(0)=0$
I'll start by giving some straight point:
$$ \int_{0}^1 g(x^n)dx = \int_{0}^1 g(t) \frac{1}{n} t^{-1+1/n}dt$$
As $g$ is continuous at $0$, for any $\delta>0$, there is a $1>\epsilon>0$ such that:
$$ |g(x)| \le \delta \quad \forall  \quad |x| \le \epsilon $$
Thus
$$ \left| \int_{0}^1 g(t) \frac{1}{n} t^{-1+1/n}dt \right| \le \underbrace{ \left( \int_{0}^{\epsilon} \delta\frac{1}{n} t^{-1+1/n}dt \right)}_{ \le \delta}+\underbrace{  \left( \int_{\epsilon}^1 |g(t)|\frac{1}{n} \epsilon^{-1+1/n}dt  \right) }_{ \le \frac{1}{n}\epsilon^{-1} \int_{0}^1 |g(t)|dt}$$
Thus ,
$$ \limsup_n  \left| \int_{0}^1 g(t) \frac{1}{n} t^{-1+1/n}dt \right|  \le \delta$$
Hence the conclusion

**Comment**

- This is okay whether the integrability is understoond in which sense, Riemann or Lesbeque.
- The formula of changing variables in the very beginning is not really necessary. A similar argument can be constructed without it, but surely more details need to be handle. Fortunately, they are just technical. The idea stays the same.